# Problem in Search From One List in Another List in Ef .Net Core

Tags: c#, list, .net-core, entity-framework-core

```
List<string> groupId = request.GroupId.Split(',').ToList();

ENTITIES.ProductGroup
       .Where(p => p.IsDisplay)
       .Where(p => p.FK_GroupNavigation.IsDisplay)
       .Where(p => groupId.Any(g => g == (p.FK_Group ?? 0) + "")
       .ToList();
```

The value in request.GroupId is `"12,15"` and the same values are in the table, but give the following error.

In Ef Core I want to search for some value in another list but it gives the following error What is the problem?

```
TargetFramework=5.0
```

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => p.IsDisplay)
> .LeftJoin(
> inner: DbSet(),
> outerKeySelector: p => EF.Property<Nullable>(p, "FK_Group"),
> innerKeySelector: g => EF.Property<Nullable>(g, "PK_Group"),
> resultSelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<ProductGroup, Group>(
> Outer = o,
> Inner = i
> ))
> .Where(p => p.Inner.IsDisplay)
> .Count(p => __groupId_0
> .Any(g => (g ?? "").Equals((object)(p.Outer.FK_Group ?? 0) + "")))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Comment: What data type is p.FK_Group? It looks like it can be nullable and if so is set to the integer value of 0, but you are comparing that value against a list of strings.  What happens if groupId contains a list of integers?

Comment: @PeterG
The compiler itself gets this error. Now the problem is something else. The post has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Any` with local collection is not translatable to SQL, use `Contains` instead. Also compare integers by integer values, query will use indexes if they are exists.

```cs
List<int> groupId = request.GroupId.Split(',').Slect(s => int.Parse(s)).ToList();

SGP_PRODUCT.ProductGroup
       .Where(p => p.IsDisplay)
       .Where(p => p.FK_GroupNavigation.IsDisplay)
       .Where(p => groupId.Contains(p.FK_Group))
       .ToList();
```